# Why red dot in one of the review queues?

Tags: support

I am seeing a red dot in one of the review queues:

[image: Red dot example]

When I click on the queue it shows no pending reviews.

Why is that, and what is the meaning of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already reported on Meta SE: [Red indicator for an empty queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301576/289691)

P.D.

The red-dot means that there are high number of items waiting for review. See [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/289691) for further details.

Related

- [New top bar is live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301845/289691)
- [The new review icon isn't an improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355236/1595451)

Comment: _high number of items waiting for review_, but there is nothing, even when I clicked on _all queues_, every queue was cleared.

Comment: Maybe you already reviewed all the items to which you have access.

Comment: @pnuts: hmm.. you are right.